# Dynamically editing a node label in treeview

Tags: .net

I have a treeview control. I just want the user to edit the text of a node for the some specified nodes alone.

In treeview control i have labeledit property which makes the text editable for all nodes in the tree but i want only the corresponding node text to be editable..

Some thing like

treeview1.nodes[1].edit=true........

Anyway to do it...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to keep LabelEdit set to true on your TreeView, but catch the [BeforeLabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforelabeledit.aspx) event and set e.CancelEdit to true whenever the user attempts to edit a node unless you want to allow it.

To programmatically initiate an edit on a node, you can use [TreeNode.BeginEdit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.beginedit.aspx).